# Java - shorter code for multiple or statements

Tags: java, if-statement

***Check if int is (1, 3, 8, 7 )***

```
int a= 1;
if (a==1 || a==3 || a==8 ....) {
   doAdd();
}
```

It is possible to shorten the "if-statement" to something like:

```
if (a==1 || 3 || 8 ...)
```

Without using an array, just interested of writing this with fewer code.

---

**First Version** (for reference only):

// Count vowels (a, o, e ,u, i )

```
[...]
String a= 'o';
if (a=='a' || a=='o' || a=='e' ....) {
   doAdd();
}
[...]
```

It is possible to shorten the "if-statement" to something like:

```
if (a=='a' || 'o' || 'e' ...)
```

I know this is no valid java, but I want to know if there is another way to do this (without looping through a "vowels-array").

Comment: Use regular expressions to shorten your code

Comment: Regular expression?  `String#contains`?

Comment: Good idea, but the vowel stuff is just an example, assume having numbers instead of strings. I am looking for a general way of shortening multiple or/and statements.

Comment: `switch` can be useful but doesn't really cut verbosity, but is often very fast in execution.

Comment: @AddingColor -  If you are asking whether you could somehow reduce the number of explicit comparisons (the `==X` code), then No, its not possible. As others have pointed out, you could use REGEX or contains() (usually at the cost of efficiency, unless you are using `switch`).

Comment: @kocko OP knows that.

Comment: This is a valid question. OP asking something valid. Why people are so hurry to downvote this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several changes in you question the simple answer is: **No**.

My answer before excluding arrays as a possible solution is:

You can add the characters to an array and use [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-char:A-char-) to determine if the character is in the array:

```
char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
...
if (Arrays.binarySearch(vowels, a) >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Please note that your array must be sorted to use this method.

Please note also that this method is not limited to work with characters but also works with other types.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Guava Chars](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html) which has some pretty neat functions. Especially have a look at

> static boolean    contains(char[] array, char target)
>   Returns true if target is present as an element anywhere in array.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this with [String.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
String str = "A";
if("aeiou".contains(str.toLowerCase())) {
   //is vowel
}
```

OR

You may try this with [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)):

```
String str = "A";
if(str.matches("(?i:a|e|i|o|u)"))) {
   //is vowel
}
```

**EDIT**

```
Integer n = 3;
if("1387".contains(n.toString())) {
   //is in list
}
```

OR

```
Integer n = 3;
if(n.toString().matches("1|3|8|7"))) {
   //is in list
}
```

Comment: This solution will not work with anything other than characters (which was an extension to the question in the second or third edit).

Answer (score 0):

```
String arr[] = {"a", "o", "e"};
String a = "a";
if (Arrays.asList(arr).contains(a)) {
  System.out.println("true");
}
```

It also can be useful with other data types not only String